# How to just reset submitted without losing the value of controls or reset the values of the form?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

How to set `submitted` property to `false` without resetting the values of the form?

I type something in the input and then hit submit button. in the submit function, I call `reset()` or `resetForm()`, which changes the `submitted` to false. But I lost the value in the input because it also reset the values.

Is it possible just to reset the `submitted` property without resetting the values of the controls on the form?

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{name}}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.io/start">
      Learn more about Angular 
    </a>

    <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(form)">
      <input name="foo" [(ngModel)]="data.foo">

      <button>sub</button>
    </form>

    submitted: {{form.submitted |json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  data = { foo: '' };

  submit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log({ form });
    console.log({ submitted: form.submitted });
    form.resetForm();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqdpun?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: `form.resetForm(form.value);`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter to the `resetForm` method, like this:

```
form.resetForm({foo:'init data'});
```

Answer (score 0):

On `resetForm` method have a parameter, and you can pass the whole data object like this:

```js
form.resetForm(this.data);
```

If you want to save the submitted field, then add in the data object also in the submit function.

```js
this.data.submitted = form.submitted;
```